# Swift protocol error: 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type

Tags: swift, protocols

What's the difference between Protocols and class-bound Protocols, and which one we should use in Swift?

```
protocol A : class { ... }

protocol A { ... }
```

We get an error when attempting to add a `weak` delegate when the Protocol is not defined as `: class`:

```
protocol A { ... }

weak var delegate: A
```

Gives the error:

> 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type

or

> 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'A'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Swift >= 4:

```
protocol A : AnyObject { ... }
```

Swift < 4:

```
protocol A : class { ... }
```

defines a ["class-only protocol"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID281): Only class types (and not structures or enumerations) can adopt this protocol.

Weak references are only defined for *reference types*. Classes
are reference types, structures and enumerations are value types.
(Closures are reference types as well, but closures cannot adopt
a protocol, so they are irrelevant in this context.)

Therefore, if the object conforming to the protocol needs to be stored in a weak property then the protocol must be a class-only protocol.

Here is another example which requires a class-only protocol:

```
protocol A { 
    var name : String { get set }
}

func foo(a : A) {
    a.name = "bar" // error: cannot assign to property: 'a' is a 'let' constant
}
```

This does not compile because for instances of structures and enumerations, `a.name = "bar"` is a mutation of `a`. If you define
the protocol as

```
protocol A : class { 
    var name : String { get set }
}
```

then the compiler knows that `a` is an instance of a class type to that
`a` is a reference to the object storage,
and `a.name = "bar"` modifies the referenced object, but not `a`.

So generally, you would define a class-only protocol if you need
the types adopting the protocol to be reference types and not value types.

Comment: In your code example you said `'a' is a 'let' constant`. I'm a little confused. What makes `a` a constant here?

Comment: @Suragch: Function parameters  – as the `a` in  `func foo(a : A)` – are by default *constants*.

Comment: _"Therefore, if your protocol **defines a weak property**"_ - Protocols don't define `weak` or `strong` properties (only `get` and `get set`); shouldn't it read: _"Therefore, if the object that conforms to the protocol needs to be stored in a weak property..."_?

Answer (score 24):

If you are using **Swift 4** or later, use `AnyObject`:

```
protocol A : AnyObject { ... }
```

Using `class` as before gives the warning and fix-it:

> Using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
>
> Replace 'class' with 'AnyObject'

Answer (score 10):

You can make the protocol derive from any class type like NSObject or AnyObject:

```
protocol TopNewsTableDelegate : AnyObject {
    func topNewsTableDidLoadedStories()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can type like this

```
@objc protocol A { ... }
```

then you can make a weak delegate reference

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol CustomProtocolName : NSObjectProtocol {
  // ...
}
```