# Crash when trying to remove KVO observer

Tags: swift, swift3, key-value-observing

I have implemented KVO for the first time and in certain conditions, it is working and the observeValue is getting called correctly. However, I'm getting a crash when trying to remove the observer in `deinit`:

> Cannot remove an observer
>    for
>   the key path "downloadInProgress" from
>   
>   because it is not registered as an observer.

...although I did register the object in `viewDidLoad`.

```
// At the top of my file
dynamic var downloadInProgress: Bool = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:  #keyPath(downloadInProgress), options: [.old,.new], context: nil)
}

deinit {
    // It crashes here
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(downloadInProgress))
}
```

Basically if `downloadInProgress = false`, it crashes. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this class is always being instantiated by a path that calls `viewDidLoad()`?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
// At the top of my file
dynamic var downloadInProgress: Bool = false
```

So it isn't part of an object? If so that might be the problem. KeyValueObserving is a technic from ObjectiveC. In Swift there are some limitations for it. One limitation is that it only works at classes that derive from NSObject. If it's a global var as I expect this isn't fulfilled.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8):

> You can use key-value observing with a Swift class, as long as the class inherits from the NSObject class

It should work if you have an object with kvo like that:

```
final class MyObject: NSObject {
   dynamic var downloadInProgress: Bool = false
}

self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:  #keyPath(myobjectinstance.downloadInProgress), options: [.old,.new], context: nil)
```

Hint: Try to avoid KVO in future, because it's uncommon in swift.

Comment: If I shouldn't use KVO, what is its replacement?

Comment: It's more a question of architecture. One solution might be to use objects and decorator pattern. I've implemented an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644972/updating-uilabel-text-when-variable-changes/43688447#43688447

Comment: There is no direct equivalent in swift. Note: It wasn't a good idea to use in ObjectiveC too.

Comment: Observer is one of those patterns that, once you understand it, you see uses for it everywhere. The indirection is very cool. You can register observers with all kinds of objects rather than wiring those objects to explicitly call you. While this indirection is a useful way to manage dependencies, it can easily be taken to extremes. Overuse of Observer tends to make systems very difficult to understand and trace.
~ Robert Martin, Agile Software Development, Chapter 24

Comment: It was only my opinion. Use it or not, your choice.

Comment: That criticism is true of every pattern.  Overuse of factories, singletons, or object pools makes code just as difficult to understand.

Comment: Thank you. I tried implementing with your solution with a new NSObject class, which I instantiate in viewDidLoad, but I am still getting the same result.